# SSIS not reading data from csv file

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a csv file which is not loading data. But it loads when i

1) open the file and save it in the same location.

2) delete any of the empty records or non empty records.

I am receiving file from ftp source. Is there any reason that why SSIS package is not loading data without doing any of the above steps.

Comment: My guesses would be line endings, character encoding or a unicode byte order mark. Do you have any tools that would let you *really* look at the fine, comparing a successful file with a failed file byte by byte? (Developer Studio's ability to open any file in its binary editor might be helpful, say, or you could probably inspect most of these properties in a decent editor like Notepad++)

Comment: No i don't have any tool to check what you are asking me to check. One thing i observed is after opening and saving the file in the same location, file size has decreased from 2.7 MB to 2.1 MB.

Comment: when it fails to read, do you get any errors, or does it act like there is no data?  Have you tried watching it in Debug and turning on some data viewers in the data flow?